# Ternary operator in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to show a component only if a variable is true, basically I'm going to create two buttons, one to set variable to false and another to true. I'm trying to use the * ngIf idea of the Angular. I need something like this:

```
render() {
 return (
  <View>
   <Button 
    title="Click me"
    onPress={ () => { this.loading = true } }
   />
   {this.loading ? <Modal /> : null}
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: Use a state variable to re-render affected data

Comment: You need to set the variable to state, otherwise the view doesn't re-render when the value changes. Also, the common convention is `{this.loading && <Modal />}`

Comment: It works, but I had to change Button to Touchable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are new to **React**, in react state and handlers are either held in **state** or passed has **props**.

you can achieve this having a component state like `show` , have click handlers which set the **State**  then in render you can check `this.state.show` and take decision to either show the component or not

```
setShow = () = >{
this.setstate({show : true});
  }

render() {
 return (
  <View>
   <Button 
    title="Click me"
    onPress={this.setShow}
   />
   {this.state.show ? <Modal /> : null}
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: It works, but I had to change Button to Touchable and I used `{this.loading && <Modal />}`